Why my bosch light doesnt work? New bike
firstly sorry about my English, but i will try my best. I've have built new bike out of the box (Rock machine e400 hybrid please see pic) with bosch system. The issue ive got is a lights it wont turn on. Cables and connections seem to be fine, I have connected it to PC (Bosc diagnostic tool),
Tried to change "light switching function" to on/off ,but system wont let me upload new settings.
There is a msg right on the top saying
"Application ID: No ebike programming available"
I take drive unit out and it seem to let me change some settings like km to miles ,
Not sure whats going on here. Is it drive uni fault or something else?

This is a brand new bike and it doesn't work out of the box?  Contact the supplier/seller/shop and advise immediately to establish a documentation trail

Do neither the front nor the rear turn on? What lights are they? Do either have independent power buttons? Do they have disconnects of any kind somewhere in the line or do they have continuous integral wires to the DU? If there are disconnects have you unplugged them and tested them with a multimeter? If there are disconnects are you sure the polarity is right?
